# Self-hosted tool for user interface design feedback

Tags: user-interface, graphic-design

I was wondering if anyone has any good tips regarding any existing self-hosted tools for providing user interface design feedback. E.g. similar to Invision, Notable, Bounce...

Mandatory criteria:

- Self-hosted.
- A way for users to provide feedback on uploaded screenshots by clicking a part of the image or selecting a certain area of the image.

Optional / ideally:

- Version control on images.
- Possibility to save image / collection of images to disk, with annotations to e.g. PDF, JPG or similar.
- Possibility to group images in projects.
- Possibility to have threads of comments (e.g. one user posts comment, which another user replies to).
- Possibility to mark comments as open/solved.
- Possibility to tag comments with e.g. groupings (e.g. "usability").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is a little old, but I was looking for this same thing and I couldn't find anything. So I built a WordPress plugin. Similar to Invision, Notable, Bounce, you can upload screenshots, and clients and colleagues can click parts of the image to comment.

Features right now are:

- Self-Hosted
- Images are grouped into projects
- Comments are threaded

Coming soon:

- Image versions
- Mark comments as open/solved
- Tag comment threads

http://projecthuddle.io

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks fantastic! Is there any newsletter or similar to sign up for to get updates when they come out? :) You should promote this plugin extensively, I'm positive it'll be extremely useful to a lot of people.

Comment: Wow, really appreciate that! Working on a newsletter signup. In the mean time, you can follow on twitter if you like http://twitter.com/projecthuddle

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% sure if this will cover all your needs but this is an open source tool:
[User Response](http://www.useresponse.com/)

Main page:
[image]

You can Upload and store files of different types in responses and comments.

Comment: Sounds unfortunately a lot more like a stackoverflow clone than a tool similar to Bounce or Invision... Does it provide the possibility to add comments on top of screenshots? If not then I'm not that interested unfortunately.

Comment: It sounds like Gallery3 might be the software you want. Version 2 has editing capabilities. 
!Gallery3[1]


  [1]: http://codex.galleryproject.org/Downloads

Comment: That doesn't look really like what I'm after either. I can't seem to find anything on whether I can comment on top of screenshots or not, only that it sounds more like an overall image gallery...